# Why brew install returns "cask is unavailable" on terminal if homebrew's website shows a different information?

Tags: installation, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install this software called Next browser. There is a page about it on [brew.sh](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/next).

When I run the command displayed on homebrew's webpage on my **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** terminal:

```
$ brew install --cask next
```

I get the following error message:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: Cask 'next' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

Observation, I am able to sucessfully install other packages like:

```
brew install hello
```

Why is this happening?

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Casks install are only available on macOS because they install macOS-specific [`.app` files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/112197/25981).

This probably explain the error you get, although it could be made clearer.